# How to modify custom category field from front end?

Tags: categories, custom-field, terms

I tried:

```
                wp_update_term($personid, 'category', array(
                  'name' => $_POST['nameChange'],
                  'slug' => $string,
                  '_city' => $_POST['newDob'],
                ));
```

Where `_city` is my category custom field.

This is how I retrieve it:

```
$fields =  get_term_meta( $cat->cat_ID ); 
$newDob = $fields['_city'][0];
```

But I am not sure how to I can change it on front end, these two are working and updating

```
'name' => $_POST['nameChange'],
'slug' => $string,
```

But not '

```
'_city' => $_POST['newDob'],
```

[I followed the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term)

Answer (score 0):

wp_update_term does not support custom fields so you will need to use update_term_meta instead.

```
update_term_meta($personid, '_dob', $_POST['newDob']);
```

Comment: ah, too late ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about where your custom field is coming from, but usually it should be stored in the term_meta database table.

You´d have to use update_term_meta:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/